# SQL JOIN with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need some help to get the data from 3 different tables.
I could research by myself but it would take a time I don't have.

What I need is:

```
Table Name     - columns needed
wp_bp_activity - item_id, user_id
wp_posts       -    ID  , -------, post_author, post_title
wp_users       - -------, user_id, -----------, ----------, display_name, user_email

WHERE type (in wp_bp_activity) = 'unit_complete' AND MONTH(date_recorded) (in wp_bp_activity) = $i
```

Could you please help me to create this query in PHP PDO?

Edited as requested:

```
wp_bp_activity:  id     user_id     component   type    action  content     primary_link    item_id     secondary_item_id   date_recorded   hide_sitewide   mptt_left   mptt_right  is_spam
wp_posts:  id   post_author     post_date   post_date_gmt   post_content    post_title  post_excerpt    post_status     comment_status  ping_status     post_password   post_name   to_ping     pinged  post_modified   post_modified_gmt   post_content_filtered   post_parent     guid    menu_order  post_type   post_mime_type  comment_count
wp_users:  id   user_login  user_pass   user_nicename   user_email  user_url    user_registered     user_activation_key     user_status     display_name
```

What I need is the information below of the 3 tables but as a single line.

The `wp_bp_activity` table will give me the `item_id` and `user_id` based on the month `WHERE date_recorded = $i` that another section of the PHP will provide.
The `item_id` `ID in wp_posts` will provide the information I need to get `post_author - author of the unit course` and `post_title - the name of the course`. After that the `user_id` will provide me in `wp_users` the `display_name - student's name` and the `user_email - student's email`.

In the end I'll display the `post_author`, `post_title`, `display_name` and `user_email` that the unit was completed `unit_complete (MONTH(date_recorded))` in April (for example) based on `item_id` and `user_id`.

Comment: Please share the full schema and state what you want as well as constraint.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are requesting.

Comment: Post the full structure for the tables and how you actually want to combine the 3. To me, its not clear what you want to achieve here other than wanting to "get data from 3 different tables"

Comment: Yes, same as georaldc, I need to know the 3 table structures and what you want from these 3 tables.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the post with the information required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following SQL query, and tell me what you get:

```
SELECT 
    activity.item_id,
    activity.user_id,
    posts.ID,
    posts.post_author,
    posts.post_title,
    users.display_name,
    users.user_email
FROM wp_bp_activity AS activity
JOIN wp_posts AS posts
    ON posts.ID = activity.item_id
JOIN wp_users AS users
    ON users.ID = activity.user_id
WHERE activity.type = 'unit_complete' 
    AND MONTH(activity.date_recorded) = $i
```

Comment: Thank you David, I'll test is ASAP and will return here to check the correct answer. But I got the idea behind the JOIN. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much David, I was able to test it out and it worked! I had to modify it a little and include other stuff but, with your answer, I was able to quickly work with it! Cheers!